# Reading input from text file C++

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

I'm suffering a problem when trying to read test scores from a text file I entered earlier in my program. The problem is  it says my variables are undefined but I think I have them defined. The writing part of the program using "ofstream" worked perfectly and gave me the output formatted in a text file.

```
1001 21 22 23 24 
1002 25 26 27 28 
1003 29 30 31 32
```

My goal has the following guidelines:
2.  Read the data from your file.
a.  Use nested loops.
b.  The outer loop will be a “while” loop and the inner loop will be a “for” loop (4 quizzes).

Here's my code below. Hopefully someone can see where I'm going wrong and point me in the right direction:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numStudents, numTests = 4, studentCount = 1, count = 1, test = 1, score = 0, testCount = 1, 
    int stuID;
    double average;
    double total;
    ofstream outputFile;
    ifstream inputFile;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

    //Open file scores.txt
    outputFile.open("Scores.txt");

    //Get the number of students
    cout << "How many students? ";
    cin >> numStudents;


    while (studentCount <= 3)
    {
        cout << "Enter Student ID: ";
        cin >> stuID;
        outputFile << stuID << " ";

        for (test = 1; test <= numTests; test++)
        {

            cout << "Enter grade for quiz " << test << ": ";
            cin >> score;
            outputFile << score << " ";
        }
        outputFile << endl;
        studentCount++;

    }

        outputFile.close(); //closes Output File

        inputFile.open("Scores.txt"); //opens Output File


    while (studentCount <= 3)
        {

        for (test = 1; test <= numTests; test++)
        {
            inputFile >> score;
            total += score;
        }

        average = total / numTests;
        inputFile >> stuID;
        cout << "The average for student " << stuID << " is " << average << endl;

        studentCount++;
        }

    inputFile.close(); //closes Input File





    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to help me by looking at this.

Comment: Are you getting a compilation error or a runtime error? What do you mean by "it says my variables are undefined"?

Comment: You are adding `score` to `total` without giving `total` an initial value, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: If you don't understand the error you are getting, please consider posting the entire text of the error instead of trying to summarize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a very trivial mistake:-

You first while loop is:-

```
while (studentCount <= 3)
```

After this your second while loop is

```
while (studentCount <= 3)
```

Since studentCount is already 4 it won't enter into this loop.

You need to re-initialise studentCount for second loop :-

```
studentCount = 1;
while (studentCount <= 3)
```

Comment: Thank you for the your help. I've been staring at this code for so long those items must have escaped my eyes!

Answer (score 0):

The comma at the end of

```
int numStudents, numTests = 4, studentCount = 1, count = 1, test = 1, score = 0, testCount = 1,
```

should be a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line of int declarations isn't terminated by ';'.
Also, StudentCount should be reset to 1, before reading inputFile and the while loop.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I didn't double check that.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the bugs I see:-
1. No semicolon in the declaration of an int and i am surprised that your compiler did not point      out that mistake.
2. You did not re-initialized your var studentcount for the second loop because the first loop sets its value to < 3.
3. You have to initialize your total to 0 (double total=0;)